# VB.NET Youtube LIKE and DISLIKE Button classes Problem for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, youtube

I have a nice tool for YouTube .... but one Problem: How is it possible to LIKE or DISLIKE a Video in the Webbrowser control. I do not find the correct classes to activate the button. The code for comments and send comment button is working...... but not like oder dislike... any ideas????

```
For Each altelm As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("BUTTON")
    If altelm.GetAttribute("classname").ToString = "yt-renderer-button" Then
        altelm.Focus()
        altelm.InvokeMember("click")
        comment_done = True
    End If
    Application.DoEvents()
Next
```

Comment: Are you sure that `yt-renderer-button` is the class of the HTML element that has the (dislike) button?. Maybe the error is there.

Comment: No not shure.... i think it is something like this:  "yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-opacity yt-uix-button-has-icon no-icon-markup like-button-renderer-like-button like-button-renderer-like-button-unclicked yt-uix-clickcard-target   yt-uix-tooltip"